# Help solving the Bass differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My ODE's are very rusty. I'm trying to find the solution to the system $$ \frac{dF}{dt} = p + qF(t) - q (F(t))^2$$
where $p,q$ are constants. I am confusing myself in the process.

First of all, am I correct in thinking that this is first-order, autonomous, and separable? So we have $$\frac{1}{p + qF(t) - q (F(t))^2} dF = dt.$$ So if we integrate both sides that should give us a solution for $t$, but even this confuses me. Aren't we really interested in finding $F$ as a function of $t$?

Comment: You can use Wolfram to integrate LHS. Once it is done, find a way solve for F.

Comment: I'm trying this, but I'm getting some weird function involving $\tan$, which I don't think is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the hyperbolic tangent $\text{arctanh(} x)$. 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \text{arctanh(} x) = \frac{1}{1 - x^2}
\end{equation}
Adjust the integrand by completing the square
\begin{align}
p +qF(t) - qF(t)^2 &= -q(F(t)^2 - F(t) - \frac{p}{q})\\
&= -q((F(t) - \frac{1}{2})^2 - (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{p}{q})
\end{align}
Plugging this into the ODE with $n^2 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{p}{q}$ and $u = F(t) - \frac{1}{2}$ 
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{q}\int \frac{du}{u^2 - n^2} &= \int dt\\
\frac{1}{n^2}\int \frac{du}{(1 - (\frac{u}{n})^2)} &= qt +c\\
\frac{n}{n^2}\int \frac{d(\frac{u}{n})}{(1 - (\frac{u}{n})^2)} &=qt + c\\
\frac{1}{n}\text{arctanh(} \frac{F(t) - \frac{1}{2}}{n}) &= qt + c
\end{align} 
This is why wolfram returns an inverse hyperbolic tangent if $p$ and $q$ are positive. If they are negative then the integral will evaluate to an inverse tangent. Now you just have to solve this equation for $F(t)$. Luckily the hyperbolic trig functions all have inverse functions in logarithms, for example
\begin{equation}
\text{arctanh(} x) = \frac{1}{2} \ln\Bigg( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \Bigg)
\end{equation}
You can now solve this equation as if it was a logarithmic equation. If you don't want to use hyperbolic trig for this integral, you can try partial fractions with $u^2 - n^2$.